# Alternative strategy to showing notifications on specific times in Android?

Tags: android, alarm

I want to be able to show notifications in the morning and evening ( a specific time let's say 7:00am in morning and 10:00pm in evening) where in I do some local database operations that generate the title of the notifications to be displayed (I traverse the tasks to be perfromed in a day and then the tasks that have been performed at the end of the day).

I am presently using alarm manager with all the valid setup reboot handling. My problem is that this alarm implementation is not punctual because of android system restrictions and battery management. I totally agree to this restriction but also cannot afford losing an alarm feature.

I am looking for alternate solutions to showing alarms at the specific time so that I don't have to worry about the system configurations and local alarms. I only need to show reminder notifications to the user at a specififc time in the morning and the evening. Do you think a server might be able to handle this use case better ? Has somebody implemented something similar in their products ?

Current alarm code:

```kotlin
    val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
      timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
      set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, MORNING_TRIGGER_HOUR)

      //Schedule for next day if early morning trigger has passed.
      if (LocalTime.now().isAfter(LocalTime.of(MORNING_TRIGGER_HOUR, 0))) {
        add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
      }

    }

    alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
      AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
      calendar.timeInMillis,
      pIntent
    )
```